# Laravel withPivot in subquery doesn't work in when clause

Tags: php, laravel

When I apply the `wherePivot` 'directly' it works, but when I apply it in a `when` clause it doesn't. I get the error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause'`

```php
return Company::where('owner_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with(['subscribers' => function ($q) {
            $q->wherePivot('is_customer', 1); // This works
            $q->when($this->type != 'all', function ($q) {
                $q->wherePivot('is_customer', 1); // This does not
            });
            $q->when($this->example != 'all', function ($q) {
                $q->where('example', 1); // This works
            });
        }
    ])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: `function ($q)` and `function ($q)`? I haven't tried to use a `->when()` clause in a `->with()` statement, but `->wherePivot()` on a base Query will look for `WHERE pivot ...`, while `->wherePivot` on a `belongsToMany()`, i.e. what your first `$q` is, has different logic. I think you just need to make sure not to define `$q` twice.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I have just updated the question, the `$q` twice does work for another regular `where` query

Comment: And? That is mostly irrelevant here... That's just a normal `where()` clause; `wherePivot()` is special; if you do it on a `belongToMany()` query (which is what the first `$q` is), it behaves differently then if you do it on a basic query... Did you even try using two different variable names? `function ($q)` as the first one, then `function ($subQ) use ($q) { $q->wherePivot(); }` as the second. If that still doesn't work, then you'll need to dig further, or you might need to ditch the `->when()` clause, and just do `if ($this->type != 'all') { $q->wherePivot(); }`

Comment: That's it, thanks! Could you add that as an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue was using the same variable `$q` as the inner and outer query:

```
Company::where(/* ... */)->with(['subscribers' => function ($q) {
  $q->when($this->type != 'all', function ($q) {
    // ...
  });
});
```

In the 1st instance, `$q` is a `belongsToMany`, as `public function subscribers()` in `Company.php` is a Many-to-many relationship, likely defined as `return $this->belongsToMany(Subscriber::class);` (or similar). When you call `$q->wherePivot(/* ... */)`, this executes a query against the Pivot table's data.

In the 2nd instance, `$q` is a basic `Builder` instance. When you call `$q->wherePivot(/* ... */)`, this executes a "magic method" query, available on all Eloquent Models. `where{Column}()`, like `whereId()`, `whereEmail()`, `wherePivot()`, etc., will execute an equivalent query like `WHERE id ...`, `WHERE email ...` and finally `WHERE pivot ...`. Since you don't have a column called `pivot` this fails.

The solution here is to not use the same variable name, and pass it forward when querying:

```
return Company::where('owner_id', auth()->user()->id)
->with(['subscribers' => function ($query) {
  $query->when($this->type != 'all', function ($subQuery) use ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('is_customer', 1);
  });
])
->firstOrFail();
```

Now, you can clearly see which instance `wherePivot()` is being called on, `$query` being the `belongsToMany()` query, and `$subQuery` being a `Builder` instance, and isn't directly used.